# How to crossfade an image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

I'm trying to crossfade an array of images, that transfer smoothly between each one, for a slideshow. I've tried fadeIn and fadeOut, and fadeTo but none seem to create the crossfade effect. None of the other articles on here could answer my question exactly.

The function isn't entirely finished, so I know the images won't reset, I'm just trying to get the crossfade to work.

```
$(function() {

    var slides = ["images/slideshow1.jpg", "images/slideshow2.jpg", "images/slideshow3.jpg", "images/slideshow4.jpg", "images/slideshow5.jpg"];        
    var slidePos = 0;

    setInterval(function() {    
        slidePos++;

        $("#slideshow-image").fadeOut(500).fadeIn(1000).attr("src", slides[slidePos]);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Actual: Image switches to next then fades out, then fades in
Expected: Cross-Fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make a second image element with the opacity of zero and have it overlap by having its position set to absolute.

Then animate its opacity to 1.0 and remove the old image element which is now hidden underneath the new one.

Then repeat this process.

You don't have to create new elements if you just have two and cycle between them.

Comment: I can't use position: absolute because I need the image to move and resize properly with the browser

Comment: Then use relative and subtract the top margin by 100%. Something like that.